# Pagina One Page se queda bloqueada con animación de JQuery

Tags: html, jquery, css

Últimamente tengo un problema con algo muy básico y se basa en lo siguiente, al hacer una animación de scroll en el `<html>` y `<body>` con JQuery, haciendo click en cualquier link que lo requiera me lleva a una parte especifica de la página web (esto todo con los `.offset().top` de los objetos), hasta ahí todo muy correcto, pero al hacer scroll tanto con el mouse como haciendo click en otro link que también debería llevarme a otra parte de la pagina, esta simplemente se queda bloqueada en la primera sección que el usuario haya seleccionado, ¿que debería hacer para solucionarlo? acá abajo dejo todo mi código, gracias. (ejecutar en pagina completa, aún no es responsive).

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  var nav = $("nav").offset().top
  var head = $("#header").offset().top
  var inicio = $("#inicio").offset().top
  var nosotros = $("#nosotros").offset().top
  var tiendas = $("#tiendas").offset().top
  var shop = $("#shop").offset().top
  var contacto = $("#contacto").offset().top

  $(window).scroll(function() {

    if($(window).scrollTop() >= nav) {

      $("nav").css({"position": "fixed"});
      $("nav").css({"top": "0"});
      $("nav").css({"transition": "0s"});

    } else {

      $("nav").css({"position": "absolute"});
      $("nav").css({"top": "55%"});
      $("nav").css({"transition": "0s"});

    }

    if($(window).scrollTop() >= inicio) {

      $("nav").css({"background-color": "rgb(61, 217, 212)"});
      $("nav h1").css({"margin-left": "0px"});
      $(".nav-cont").css({"padding-right": "3%"});
      $(".in").css({"font-weight": "600"});


    } else {

      $("nav").css({"background-color": "transparent"});
      $("nav h1").css({"margin-left": "-150px"});
      $(".nav-cont").css({"padding-right": "33%"});
      $(".in").css({"font-weight": "400"});

    };

    if($(window).scrollTop() >= nosotros) {

      $(".in").css({"font-weight": "400"});
      $(".nos").css({"font-weight": "600"});

    } else {

      $(".nos").css({"font-weight": "400"});

    };

    if($(window).scrollTop() >= tiendas) {

      $(".nos").css({"font-weight": "400"});
      $(".ti").css({"font-weight": "600"});

    } else {

      $(".ti").css({"font-weight": "400"});

    };

    if($(window).scrollTop() >= shop) {

      $(".ti").css({"font-weight": "400"});
      $(".sh").css({"font-weight": "600"});

    } else {

      $(".sh").css({"font-weight": "400"});

    };

    if($(window).scrollTop() >= contacto) {

      $(".sh").css({"font-weight": "400"});
      $(".cont").css({"font-weight": "600"});

    } else {

      $(".cont").css({"font-weight": "400"});

    };

    $(".in").on("click", function(){

      $("html, body").animate({scrollTop: inicio},500);

    });

    $(".nos").on("click", function(){

      $("html, body").animate({scrollTop: nosotros},500);

    });

    $(".ti").on("click", function(){

      $("html, body").animate({scrollTop: tiendas},500);

    });

    $(".sh").on("click", function(){

      $("html, body").animate({scrollTop: shop},500);

    });

    $(".cont").on("click", function(){

      $("html, body").animate({scrollTop: contacto},500);

    });

  });

});
```

```css
* {

  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;

}

html, body {

  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 0;
  padding: 0 0;

}

.sect {

  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;

}

nav {

  height: 10%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: transparent;
  position: absolute;
  transition: .2s;
  top: 55%;

}

nav h1 {

  font-size: 2.3em;
  padding-top: 0.3em;
  padding-left: 0.4em;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  margin-left: -150px;
  transition: .2s;

}

nav h1 span {

 color: white;

}

.nav-cont {

  float: right;
  margin-top: -32px;
  padding-right: 33%;
  transition: .2s;

}

.nav-cont ul {

  list-style: none;

}

.nav-cont ul li {

  float: left;

}

.nav-cont ul li a {

  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: white;
  font-weight: 400;

}

.nav-cont ul li a:hover {

  font-weight: 600;

}

header {

  background-image: url("../img/3D8.jpg");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: top;
  background-size: cover;
  background-attachment: fixed;

}

.header-cover {

  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.31);

}

.title-container {

  padding-top: 19%;

}

.title-container h1 {

  text-align: center;
  font-size: 5em;

}

.title-container h1 span {

  color: white;

}

#prefooter {

  height: 25px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: rgb(233, 66, 66);

}

#prefooter p {

  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  font-size: 10px;
  font-style: italic;
  padding-top: 6px;
  cursor: pointer;

}

footer {

  height: 50px;
  background-color: rgb(217, 61, 61);

}

footer p {

  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  font-weight: 500;
  padding-top: 15px;

}

footer p span {

  background-color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: .2s;
  -webkit-transition: ,2s;

}

footer p span:hover {

  background-color: transparent;

}
```

```html
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Maxipet Maqueta</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/master.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./js/main.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <nav>
      <h1>Maxi<span>pet</span></h1>
        <div class="nav-cont">
          <ul>
            <li><a class="in" href="#inicio">Inicio</a>
            </li><li><a class="nos" href="#nosotros">Nosotros</a>
            </li><li><a class="ti" href="#tiendas">Tiendas</a>
            </li><li><a class="sh" href="#shop">Productos</a>
            </li><li><a class="cont" href="#contacto">Contacto</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
    <header id="header" class="sect">
      <div class="header-cover">
         <div class="title-container">
           <h1>Maxi<span>pet</span></h1>
         </div>
      </div>
    </header>
    <section id="inicio" class="sect">

    </section>
    <section id="nosotros" class="sect">

    </section>
    <section id="tiendas" class="sect">

    </section>
    <section id="shop" class="sect">

    </section>
    <section id="contacto" class="sect">

    </section>
    <section id="prefooter">
      <p>Mas información</p>
    </section>
    <footer><p>© Maxpet 2017 - Made With ❤ By <span>Crawford</span></p></footer>
  </body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema ocurre porque estás asociando el controlador de los eventos `click` del menú dentro del controlador del `scroll`. Eso es un problema porque cada vez que se dispara el evento `scroll` de la ventana estás asociando un evento click.

Creo que porque se acaban asociando demasiados controladores de evento (y contradictorios) que cuando le das click a uno de los menús varias veces (provocando un *scroll* y asociando aún más eventos) el sistema se acaba cayendo por su propio peso (aunque esto es una teoría, tendría que mirarlo más detenidamente para ver si ese es el motivo real).

Mueve los controladores del evento `click` fuera del `$(window).scroll(function() { ... })` y parece que ya funciona sin problemas:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  var nav = $("nav").offset().top
  var head = $("#header").offset().top
  var inicio = $("#inicio").offset().top
  var nosotros = $("#nosotros").offset().top
  var tiendas = $("#tiendas").offset().top
  var shop = $("#shop").offset().top
  var contacto = $("#contacto").offset().top

  $(window).scroll(function() {

    if($(window).scrollTop() >= nav) {

      $("nav").css({"position": "fixed"});
      $("nav").css({"top": "0"});
      $("nav").css({"transition": "0s"});

    } else {

      $("nav").css({"position": "absolute"});
      $("nav").css({"top": "55%"});
      $("nav").css({"transition": "0s"});

    }

    if($(window).scrollTop() >= inicio) {

      $("nav").css({"background-color": "rgb(61, 217, 212)"});
      $("nav h1").css({"margin-left": "0px"});
      $(".nav-cont").css({"padding-right": "3%"});
      $(".in").css({"font-weight": "600"});


    } else {

      $("nav").css({"background-color": "transparent"});
      $("nav h1").css({"margin-left": "-150px"});
      $(".nav-cont").css({"padding-right": "33%"});
      $(".in").css({"font-weight": "400"});

    };

    if($(window).scrollTop() >= nosotros) {

      $(".in").css({"font-weight": "400"});
      $(".nos").css({"font-weight": "600"});

    } else {

      $(".nos").css({"font-weight": "400"});

    };

    if($(window).scrollTop() >= tiendas) {

      $(".nos").css({"font-weight": "400"});
      $(".ti").css({"font-weight": "600"});

    } else {

      $(".ti").css({"font-weight": "400"});

    };

    if($(window).scrollTop() >= shop) {

      $(".ti").css({"font-weight": "400"});
      $(".sh").css({"font-weight": "600"});

    } else {

      $(".sh").css({"font-weight": "400"});

    };

    if($(window).scrollTop() >= contacto) {

      $(".sh").css({"font-weight": "400"});
      $(".cont").css({"font-weight": "600"});

    } else {

      $(".cont").css({"font-weight": "400"});

    };

  });
  
  $(".in").on("click", function(){

      $("html, body").animate({scrollTop: inicio},500);

    });

    $(".nos").on("click", function(){

      $("html, body").animate({scrollTop: nosotros},500);

    });

    $(".ti").on("click", function(){

      $("html, body").animate({scrollTop: tiendas},500);

    });

    $(".sh").on("click", function(){

      $("html, body").animate({scrollTop: shop},500);

    });

    $(".cont").on("click", function(){

      $("html, body").animate({scrollTop: contacto},500);

    });


});
```

```css
* {

  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;

}

html, body {

  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 0;
  padding: 0 0;
background:#ccc;
}

.sect {

  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;

}

nav {

  height: 10%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: transparent;
  position: absolute;
  transition: .2s;
  top: 55%;

}

nav h1 {

  font-size: 2.3em;
  padding-top: 0.3em;
  padding-left: 0.4em;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  margin-left: -150px;
  transition: .2s;

}

nav h1 span {

 color: white;

}

.nav-cont {

  float: right;
  margin-top: -32px;
  padding-right: 33%;
  transition: .2s;

}

.nav-cont ul {

  list-style: none;

}

.nav-cont ul li {

  float: left;

}

.nav-cont ul li a {

  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: white;
  font-weight: 400;

}

.nav-cont ul li a:hover {

  font-weight: 600;

}

header {

  background-image: url("../img/3D8.jpg");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: top;
  background-size: cover;
  background-attachment: fixed;

}

.header-cover {

  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.31);

}

.title-container {

  padding-top: 19%;

}

.title-container h1 {

  text-align: center;
  font-size: 5em;

}

.title-container h1 span {

  color: white;

}

#prefooter {

  height: 25px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: rgb(233, 66, 66);

}

#prefooter p {

  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  font-size: 10px;
  font-style: italic;
  padding-top: 6px;
  cursor: pointer;

}

footer {

  height: 50px;
  background-color: rgb(217, 61, 61);

}

footer p {

  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  font-weight: 500;
  padding-top: 15px;

}

footer p span {

  background-color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: .2s;
  -webkit-transition: ,2s;

}

footer p span:hover {

  background-color: transparent;

}
```

```html
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Maxipet Maqueta</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/master.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./js/main.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <nav>
      <h1>Maxi<span>pet</span></h1>
        <div class="nav-cont">
          <ul>
            <li><a class="in" href="#inicio">Inicio</a>
            </li><li><a class="nos" href="#nosotros">Nosotros</a>
            </li><li><a class="ti" href="#tiendas">Tiendas</a>
            </li><li><a class="sh" href="#shop">Productos</a>
            </li><li><a class="cont" href="#contacto">Contacto</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
    <header id="header" class="sect">
      <div class="header-cover">
         <div class="title-container">
           <h1>Maxi<span>pet</span></h1>
         </div>
      </div>
    </header>
    <section id="inicio" class="sect">

    </section>
    <section id="nosotros" class="sect">

    </section>
    <section id="tiendas" class="sect">

    </section>
    <section id="shop" class="sect">

    </section>
    <section id="contacto" class="sect">

    </section>
    <section id="prefooter">
      <p>Mas información</p>
    </section>
    <footer><p>© Maxpet 2017 - Made With ❤ By <span>Crawford</span></p></footer>
  </body>
```

Comment: Aparte de eso, el código podría reducirse y simplificarse si usaras más clases para los menús y generalizases algo más lo que ocurre cuando se hace scroll.

Comment: Muchas gracias, es perfecto.